# SSIS couldn't access datafile on remote server

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssis, etl

We have a simple SSIS package that imports a flat file into a table. The only problem is that the flat file resides on a network share, now the only time i have a problem is when I try to execute it from SSMS on my local machine.

- So my machine is ws1 running Sql Server management studio (SSMS)
- The instance runs on srv1
- The flat file resides a network share share1 on srv2
- So the connection string is \srv2\share1\folder\file.txt
- The error i get is: `cannot open the datafile
  "\\srv2\share1\folder\file.txt"`

when i run it with SSMS on srv1 it works like a charm! i only get this error on ws1...

Here's some more information:

- share1 has full permissions to everyone.
- the SSIS service account runs under a domain account.
- I'm trying to execute the package from SSISDB not from MSDB.

### **Addition 04/04/2013**

I ran Process Monitor (procmon) on it and this is the results:

- When it's executed on srv1 it starts with a `QueryOpen` operation, createFile, ReadFile and so on and so forth everything results in `SUCCESS`...
- When it's executed on ws1 it starts with a FileSystemControl Operation and the path is `\\srv2\IPC$` and the result is `NO SUCH DEVICE`, Detail is `Control: FSCTL_DFS_GET_REFERRALS` then it has another `FileSystemContro` Operation which succeeds and the Detail is `Control: FSCTL_NETWORK_DELETE_CONNECTION`, then it has a lot of attempts to access the file `\\srv2\share1\folder\file.txt` but `ACCESS DENIED` for all...
- Sure enough when i look in the properties the user is a domain user which has access to the share since it's shared to everyone...

Could anyone define this mystery?

Comment: Try creating a mapped drive to the files location and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: @MarkKram On which account? mine, SSIS service account (which is no interactive so i couldnt) or on the SQL Server service account?

Comment: Eli, I do a lot of integration and migration work and this is always a problem. Typically, I make sure that the customer move and data extracts to a local drive so that there usually aren't any pesky Windows permissions and/or policies issues. That is my recommendation to you.

Comment: @MarkKram unfortunately I can't change the location of the files since there're a lot of other process's that resides on this.

Comment: How about just simply copying the file manually?

Comment: @MarkKram i want things to run programmatic, and i don't prefer having a copy process in the middle... I remember solving this problem previously stupid me didn't document it...

Comment: I agree but somethings things are beyond your control, good luck!

Comment: Just to clarify, what server is Share1 living on?  UNC paths are specified in the format \\server\share\folder\file, so the error you are getting is that SSIS can't access the server "Share1" to get to the share called "folder", from what you have written above it appears to be the case anyway.

Comment: @steoleary it's on srv2 (see my edition)...

Comment: Would having your SQL Agent account reach out and copy the file locally solve your problem? I often find it's cleaner to have a precursor step in my agents to handle queuing of files so that when my package launches, I *know* the files are there and we are ready to process. Also helps reduce permission oddities like you are experiencing.

Comment: @billinkc No, i want to execute it within a sp and pass in some params...

Comment: When you run it in SSMS, are you running it from the browser tree, from a stored procedure, or from SQL Agent? Each of these run under different user accounts, and it's likely that the user account is the problem. If you want to isolate exactly whats going on, use procmon to find out what the process is running under and fix it accordingly.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Finally someone starts talking! i run it from the browser tree and from an SP (i think it's the same the GUI is executing an SP try to script it you'll see...) but it should be either the account the intense is running under or the SSIS service account and both have access...

Comment: So you can see what account Procmon indicates the file copy is failing under? So go into explorer and navigate to the share, right click on the file go to the security tab, press advanced, effective permissions, type in your user and see what permissions that user has.  It will only confirm that the user doesn't have permissions. But at least you know which user it is. BTW what version of SQL Server are you using? Also you know that shares have two points of security, the share security and the local file security?

Comment: @ElectricLlama Come on I have access to the share! it's the same user that access it trough srv1, do you have any idea what ipc$ is? maybe somehow this comes in to play and that's the reason i can't get trough?

Comment: I guess I won't be able to help any further.